# Spring Security - Principal is always null using RouterFunction

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-webflux

I'm using Spring WebFlux with `RouterFunction` to define my API endpoints. I have Spring Security configured the following way:

```
@Bean
fun security(httpSecurity: ServerHttpSecurity): SecurityWebFilterChain {
    return httpSecurity
            .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
            // disable default security
                .httpBasic().disable()
                .formLogin().disable()
                .logout().disable()
                .csrf().disable()
            .addFilterAt(apiAuthenticationWebFilter(), SecurityWebFiltersOrder.AUTHENTICATION)
            .authorizeExchange()
                .pathMatchers("/app/health").permitAll()
                .pathMatchers("/app/info", "/app/loggers", "/app/metrics").hasAuthority(SecurityRole.SYSTEM)
                .anyExchange()
                .authenticated()
            .and()
                .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationFailureHandler)
            .and()
            .build()
}

@Bean
fun securityContextRepository(): NoOpServerSecurityContextRepository {
    return NoOpServerSecurityContextRepository.getInstance()
}

private fun apiAuthenticationWebFilter(): AuthenticationWebFilter {
    val apiAuthenticationWebFilter = AuthenticationWebFilter(authenticationManager)
    apiAuthenticationWebFilter.setAuthenticationFailureHandler(ServerAuthenticationEntryPointFailureHandler(jwtAuthenticationFailureHandler))
    apiAuthenticationWebFilter.setAuthenticationConverter(jwtAuthenticationConverter)
    apiAuthenticationWebFilter.setRequiresAuthenticationMatcher(PathPatternParserServerWebExchangeMatcher("/**"))
    apiAuthenticationWebFilter.setSecurityContextRepository(securityContextRepository())
    return apiAuthenticationWebFilter
}
```

`RouterFunction` is declared like this:

```
@Bean
fun apiRouter(testHandler: TestHandler,
              errorHandler: ErrorHandler): RouterFunction<*> = router {
    (accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8).nest {
        GET(TEST_PATH, testHandler::test )
    })
}.andOther(route(RequestPredicates.all(), HandlerFunction { errorHandler.notFoundResponse() }))
```

And the handler itself:

```
@Component
class TestHandler(private val testService: TestService) {

    fun test(request: ServerRequest): Mono<ServerResponse> {
        return request.toMono()
                .transform({ testResponse() })
    }
```

The issue is that `request.principal()` is always null the same as the `ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.getContext().block()` result, however authentication configuration works correctly and authenticates user. Interesting point that declaring endpoint using annotated controllers principal is *not null* and shows correctly authenticated user.

```
@RestController
class TestController(private val testService: TestService) {

    @GetMapping("/test")
    fun test(principal: Principal): Mono<String> {
        return testService.test().map { message -> message + " " + principal.name }
    }
}
```

Is it misconfiguration or a bug? There are similar questions asked, maybe it's the same issue?

**SAMPLE**:

Repo - https://github.com/yyunikov/spring-boot-2-kotlin-starter/

Line - https://github.com/yyunikov/spring-boot-2-kotlin-starter/blob/master/api/src/main/kotlin/com/yunikov/api/test/TestHandler.kt#L18

Curl example:

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJqdGkiOiJhNjQyMjk0NC01ZDFkLTQxODItOGE2ZS1mZGM0NjEwYzhlNTYiLCJzdWIiOiJ5dW5pa292IiwiaWF0IjoxNTIzNzQyNzcxLCJpc3MiOiJodHRwOi8vbG9jYWxob3N0OjgwODAvIiwiZW1haWwiOiJ1c2VyQHl1bmlrb3YuY29tIiwicm9sZXMiOlsidXNlciJdfQ.RirM-t7GZnSDQIAn_J-thD1UAzdyxKmiR4ktA_BdlYZsFoYKzy5nj-1dBaG60o7M9FcfwFLAWEe4pc7DplDNjw" localhost:8080/test
```

Comment: Could this be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48156572/null-principal-returned-by-serverrequest-in-webflux-request-handler/48956611?noredirect=1#comment86848226_48956611 ?

Comment: @dmendezg Indeed, seems that it is working via `flatMap`, can you explain why `request.principal().block()` returns null? Isn't blocking should wait for result to be available?

Comment: However flat mapping `ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.getContext()` still doesn't return a security object, why it's happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The internal implementation is based on a delegator, so it returns null if it hasn't been resolved yet (this behavior results in an exception now)

Here is an example on how to get both.

```
fun secure(serverRequest: ServerRequest): Mono<ServerResponse> {
    return Mono.zip(
        serverRequest.principal(),
        ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.getContext()
    )
        .flatMap {
            val principal = it.t1 // Not null
            Assert.notNull(principal)
            val securityContext = it.t2 // Not null
            Assert.notNull(securityContext)
            ServerResponse.ok().body(fromObject("Hello $principal!"))
        }
}
```

Notice that the use of `block()/blockFirst()/blockLast()` will result in an exception as an `IllegalStateException`